# Is it possible to hide pages from an Azure DevOps Wiki?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I have been tasked with documenting how we are going to use Azure DevOps. This is something new to our team.

I am working on a wiki for the vaious How Tos, guides, standards, etc.

I want to force users to read pages in a certain order. But I don't necessarily want them to go directly to a page in the tree.

Here is my structure

[image]

So for Repos, if the reader needs to migrate an existing git repo to Azure DevOps, I want to the read

1. Create a New DevOps Repo
2. Change Local Repositories to Azure DevOps
3. Push Existing Git Repository to Azure DevOps

But I don't want those pages visible in the tree. I will have another page with links to these pages.

Is this even possible? My research has yielded little in the way of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief I'd say no. You can't do all you've outlined using Azure DevOps Wiki. I believe I heard these needs:

1. **Hide pages from an Azure DevOps Wiki. Yes**. We could do this a number of ways, e.g., clone the underlying Git repository and work/edit locally until you are ready to share it. Not really what you are looking for. You could also futz with permissions but, again, not really what you're looking for.
2. **Force users to read pages in a specific order. No**. I don't believe this can be done. It's contrary to [Wiki Design Principles](https://wiki.c2.com/?WikiDesignPrinciples).
3. **Dynamically hide and later dynamically show a page(s) in the right-hand menu. No**. I don't believe this can be done. It's contrary to [Wiki Design Principles](https://wiki.c2.com/?WikiDesignPrinciples).

Azure DevOps Wiki could be made to meet some of these needs but I know of no way to stitch them together as you've outlined.

**It sounds like you want to create a tightly orchestrated computer-based-training course (CBT).** Wiki isn't the right tool for that. Wiki is more about open, loosely-structured, collaborative knowledge sharing.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Much appreciated. To your point, we want both. The documentation I am writing will be used for training as well as for reference. Thank you

Comment: In cases such as your I've had positive results using Wiki to draft the desired documentation - kind of treating the Wiki pages as "source code" - and then generating/transforming that documentation into the desired format (CBT in your case).Tools like Padoc (and others) can be helpful.

http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Answer (score 7):

Files and folders starting with a '.' are now ignored...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366488/hide-folders-in-wiki-like-pages.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite possible. Since Wikis supports links (even relative links). You can set up Next and Previous links in each page to force people reading the documents in a certain order.

The files can easily be hidden by starting the file name with a dot as in `.HideMe.md`.

The Tree structure can also be replaced alltogether if you add an `.order` file per folder.

Read more about DevOps Wiki at [MS Docs - Wiki files and file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-file-structure?view)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will take this under advisement.

Comment: @Dennis That's a clever hack that mostly meets the original ask. Creative.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following link from Microsoft, answer is **NO** :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops#faq

[image]